# Combinatorics recursion question.

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

How many binary vectors of length n do not contain a sequence '001' ? Solve by
recursion and explain your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be the number of sequences not containing the sequece $001$ ending in $0$ and $1$, respectively. Given a desired sequence of length $n$, we can always add a $0$ at the end of it, so
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$$
To get sequences ending in $1$ of length $n+1$, we can add $1$ to a sequence of length $n$ ending in  $1$, or add $01$ to a sequence of length $n-1$, also ending in $1$. Hence
$$b_{n+1}=b_n+b_{n-1}$$
As we have $a_1=1,a_2=2,b_1=1$ and $b_2=2$, $b_n=F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), and $a_n$ can be calculated with the use of a telescopic sum to yield
$$a_n=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^nF_n-F_1=1+F_{n+2}-1-1=F_{n+2}-1,$$
where was used the property of the sum of the $n$ first Fibonacci numbers stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Combinatorial_Identities). So, the number $x_n$ of sequences disered is
$$x_n=a_n+b_n=F_{n+2}-1+F_{n+1}=F_{n+3}-1.$$
For an explicit form in terms of $n$, just check the link.